# How to load a library at a specific address in IDA and re-analyze the program statically?

Tags: ida, debugging, idapython, unpacking, ida-plugin

I have a dumped PE that has calls like

```
call    ds:dword_4010B4
```

now these are actually addresses of APIs in kernel32.dll

my problem is IDA doesn't know that these are kernel32 APIs and therefore in the decompiler all i see is stuff like

```
MEMORY[address](&v1, "explorer.exe %s", &v2);
```

which are API calls without names

so how can i sync these API calls with their actual names? is there any way i can tell IDA that for example kernel32.dll is loaded at address x so it can therefore load it there statically or  dynamically and resolve these names ?

Comment: Does that dumped PE resolves that called function at runtime? If yes look for any `GetProcAddress`. Then attach a debugger, set a breakpoint there and investigate...